# Generating the best-fit formula for given data

Tags: fitting, interpolation, data

I have three independent variables and one dependent variable, I want to generate a new formula for calculating the dependent one using the three independent ones, I have the data series like below:

```
x(1), x(11), x(111), y(1)
x(2), x(22), x(222), y(2)
.
.
.
x(n), x(nn), x(nnn), y(n)
```

which for each `y(i)` there is three corresponding `x(i), x(ii), x(iii)`. Indeed the value of the `y(i)` depends on the values of `x(i), x(ii)` and `x(iii)`.

In the end, I want to generate a formula like:

```
 y = f[x1, x2 , x3]
```

Comment: What have you tried in *Mathematica*?  Do you have an example data set?

Comment: To make a fit you must have a model. If you don't have a model in mind, you might try making and interpolation function. See [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) in the Documentation Center. If you do have a model in mind, please edit your question to describe the model. Do not use the comments facility to describe the model.